levenberg marquardt implementation in matlab problem code no converges
I am trying to implement levenberg marquardt algorithm in matlab but my code doesn't converge and errors keep getting bigger and bigger after first iteration. I checked jacobian table, inverse function and so on but I couldn't figure it out what is the problem.
I look for the jacobian and calculated both by using numerical differentiation and by calculating partial derivative formulas and calculating by matrix operations.
I tried build in inverse function and cholesky factorization
I calculated the matrix and bias calculation, done in the code, with Excel table and formulas and checked the values.
Code find a low residual error at first bu after calculating jacobian and finding the delta_value and changing the weights in second or third iteration the norm of residuals getting bigger and bigger.
Is there anything that I can't see?
clear; clc;
% Define hyperparameters
epoch = 10;            % Maximum number of epochs
tol = 0.02;             % Tolerance for convergence
lambda = 0.01;          % Initial regularization parameter
layer_number = 3;       % number of layer(input and output are included)
input_size= 1;          % Number of input features
hidden_size = 15;       % Number of neurons in the hidden layer
output_size = 1;        % Number of outputs
num_runs = 5;           % Number of runs to calculate average
number_of_sample=46;    % Number of sample

% Create training data for problem one Sinus wave y = 1/2 + 1/4sin(37pix)
input_vals = linspace(-1, 1, number_of_sample)';        % 40 inputs scattered in the interval [-1, 1]
target_vals = 0.5 + 0.25 * sin(3 * pi * input_vals);    % Target output according to given formula

% Run the algorithm 5 times for calculating average error to create plot
errors_of_epochs_for_average_5_run = zeros(epoch,1); 
for run = 1:num_runs
    
    W1 = rand(hidden_size,input_size);
    b1 = rand(hidden_size,1);
    W2 = rand(output_size,hidden_size);
    b2 = rand(output_size,1);
    
    parameterVector= [W1(:);b1(:);W2(:);b2];                       %parameter vector for jacobian matrix;
    

    errors_of_epochs = zeros(epoch,1);                          % to store error values of each epoch
    for epoch_number = 1:epoch
        % Initialize matrix to store error vectors for each run
        output_vals=zeros(number_of_sample,output_size);        %outputs for all samples
        errors_for_each=zeros(number_of_sample,output_size);    %error values for each input output value
        
        %forwardpass loop
        for i=1:number_of_sample
            output_vals(i,output_size) = forward_pass(input_vals(i,input_size), W1, b1, W2, b2);
        end
       errors_for_each = target_vals - output_vals;
       error_norm = norm(errors_for_each);
       errors_of_epochs(epoch_number,1) = error_norm;        % calculate average sum of square for each epoch
       ***parameterVector= [W1(:);b1(:);W2(:);b2];              % recreate paramVector with new weights***
       Jaco=jacobian(parameterVector, target_vals, input_vals,hidden_size); % calculate jacobian

       while true               % to calculate delta again when error is bigger than previous one
           
           JTJ=Jaco'*Jaco;
          
           I=eye(size(JTJ));
           JTJ_Lambda_Eye=JTJ+lambda*I;
           JTe=Jaco'*errors_for_each;
           try
                [R,Flag]=chol(JTJ_Lambda_Eye);
                if Flag
                    disp('Matrix must be symmetric and positive definite.');
                    
                end
                   
                % JTJLEyeInverse=inv(JTJ_Lambda_Eye);
    
                L = chol(JTJ_Lambda_Eye, 'lower');
                n=size(JTJ_Lambda_Eye,1);
                I=eye(n);
                Y=zeros(n);
                % Solve for Y using forward substitution
                for i = 1:n
                    Y(:, i) = L \ I(:, i);
                end
                % Now solve L^T * X = Y for X
                JTJLEyeInverse = L' \ Y;
           catch
                disp('Cholesky factorization failed.');
                break;
           end
           deltaValue=JTJLEyeInverse*JTe;
           parameterVectorTest=parameterVector;
           parameterVectorTest=parameterVectorTest-deltaValue;
           % check wheather the new error create better value.
           W1_test = reshape(parameterVectorTest(1:hidden_size * input_size), hidden_size, input_size);
           b1_test = reshape(parameterVectorTest(hidden_size * input_size + 1:hidden_size * input_size + hidden_size),hidden_size, input_size);
           W2_test = reshape(parameterVectorTest(hidden_size * input_size + hidden_size + 1:end - 1), output_size, hidden_size);
           b2_test = parameterVectorTest(end);

           %test delta value whether they are too small for change or not
           if norm(deltaValue)<tol;
               disp("Parameter changes are too small to continue");
               break;
           end
           %test feedforward
           test_output_vals=zeros(number_of_sample,output_size);
           for i=1:number_of_sample
               test_output_vals(i,output_size) = forward_pass(input_vals(i,input_size), W1_test, b1_test, W2_test, b2_test);
           end

           test_errors_for_each = target_vals - test_output_vals;
           test_error_norm = norm(test_errors_for_each);
           
           if test_error_norm > errors_of_epochs(epoch_number,1)
               lambda=lambda*10;
               % if lambda>1000
               %     lambda=1000;
               % end
           else
               break;
           end
       end %finis point of bigger error and increasing lambda

       if test_error_norm <= errors_of_epochs(epoch_number,1)
           W1=W1_test;
           b1=b1_test;
           W2=W2_test;
           b2=b2_test;
           lambda=max(lambda/10, 1e-7);
       end
       
       if test_error_norm <= tol
           disp(['Converged at epoch ', num2str(epoch_number), ' in run ', num2str(run)]);
           break;
       end

    end

    errors_of_epochs_for_average_5_run = errors_of_epochs_for_average_5_run + errors_of_epochs; %to calculate average of 5 run

end

% Plotting the result for investigating
% Calculate the average error across all runs
avg_epoch_errors = mean(errors_of_epochs_for_average_5_run, 1);

% Plot average error vs. epochs
plot_target=zeros(number_of_sample ,1);
 for i_test = 1:input_size
    X_test = input_vals(i_test);
    % Forward pass to get the current output
    plot_target(i_test) = forward_pass(X_test, W1, b1, W2, b2);
    % Calculate the current error  
end
figure;
hold on;
%plot(1:biggest_last_epoch_number, avg_epoch_errors(1:biggest_last_epoch_number), '-o');
plot(input_vals, target_vals, 'r-o');
plot(input_vals, plot_target, 'b-o');
xlabel('Epoch');
ylabel('Average Error');
title('Average Error per Epoch across 5 Runs');
grid on;
hold off;


% Define forward pass function
function [outputf,A1] = forward_pass(X, W1, b1, W2, b2)
    Z1 = (W1 * X) + b1;                 % Linear combination for hidden layer
    A1 = sigmoid(Z1);                  % Sigmoid activation for hidden layer
    Z2 = (W2 * A1) + b2;                % Linear combination for output layer
    outputf = Z2;                      % Output layer
end
% Sigmoid activation function
function cikti = sigmoid(x)
    cikti = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-x));
end

% Derivative of the sigmoid function
function cikti = sigmoidDerivative(x)
    cikti = sigmoid(x) .* (1 - sigmoid(x));
end

% Define function for calculating Jacobian
function jaco_return=jacobian(jparameterVector, jtarget_vals, jinput_vals,jhidden_size)
    jaco_return=zeros(length(jtarget_vals), length(jparameterVector));
    W1 = reshape(jparameterVector(1:jhidden_size * 1), jhidden_size, 1);
    b1 = reshape(jparameterVector(jhidden_size * 1 + 1:jhidden_size * 1 + jhidden_size),jhidden_size, 1);
    W2 = reshape(jparameterVector(jhidden_size * 1 + jhidden_size + 1:end - 1), 1, jhidden_size);
    b2 = jparameterVector(end);
    for i=1:length(jtarget_vals)            % to creat each line of jacobian for each input output pair
        [~ , jA1] = forward_pass(jinput_vals(i),W1,b1,W2,b2);
        derivW1 = -1 * W2'.* sigmoidDerivative(jA1) *jinput_vals(i);    %W1 partial derivatives
        derivb1 = -1 * W2'.* sigmoidDerivative(jA1);                    %b1 partial derivatives
        derivW2 = -1 * jA1;                                             %W2 partial derivatives
        derivb2 = -1;                                                   %b2 partial derivatives linear activation function
        jaco_return(i,:)= [derivW1(:);derivb1(:);derivW2(:);derivb2]; %each line of jacobian matrix       
    end
    epsilon=1e-10;
    jaco_test=zeros(length(jtarget_vals), length(jparameterVector));
    jparameterVector_pus=jparameterVector;
   
    for jsatir=1:length(jtarget_vals)
        for jsutun=1:length(jparameterVector)
            outpus_test_normal=forward_pass(jinput_vals(jsatir),W1,b1,W2,b2);
        
            jparameterVector_pus(jsutun)=jparameterVector(jsutun)+epsilon;
        
            W1_test = reshape(jparameterVector_pus(1:jhidden_size * 1), jhidden_size, 1);
            b1_test = reshape(jparameterVector_pus(jhidden_size * 1 + 1:jhidden_size * 1 + jhidden_size),jhidden_size, 1);
            W2_test = reshape(jparameterVector_pus(jhidden_size * 1 + jhidden_size + 1:end - 1), 1, jhidden_size);
            b2_test = jparameterVector_pus(end);
            jparameterVector_pus(jsutun)=jparameterVector(jsutun);
            output_vals_test_plus = forward_pass(jinput_vals(jsatir),W1_test,b1_test,W2_test,b2_test);
            jaco_test(jsatir, jsutun)=((output_vals_test_plus- outpus_test_normal)/epsilon)*-1;
        end
    end
    jaco_return=jaco_test;
end


I have found one error. Mistakenly, I forget to set the parameterVector with the new weight just before the second call of the jacobian function. But the model still can't converge. I checked input and output values with ready made function in MatLab. It works with no problem. There is still convergence problem but this time error function not increasing but stuck around 1.

Please extract the part that that does the optimization, the part that you replace with a MATLAB function and found to be wrong. And then only post that part, with a small driver script that sets the input values. The rest is irrelevant to your question, and just makes it harder for us to help you. See [mre].

Thank you for your comment Cris Luengo. I will try to create minimal reproducible example hereafter. I have found problem finally. lambda optimization pars lambda=lambda*10 and lambda=lambda/10 are stuck and the algorithm repeatedly increase and decrease the lambda. I have changed the code "test_error_norm <= errors_of_epochs(epoch_number,1)" to "test_error_norm <= errors_of_epochs(epoch_number,1)*0.80" and prevent the unnecessary repeated change. Looks like lambda change should be done carefully.

if so, then please either post a self-answer or delete the question altogether

function cikti = sigmoidDerivative(x)
cikti = sigmoid(x) .* (1 - sigmoid(x));

This code part has to be changed to
function cikti = sigmoidDerivative(x)
cikti = x .* (1 - x);

because in the Jacobean function, the "sigmodiDerivative()" funtion is called with parameter that already calculated with sigmoid() function
[~ , jA1] = forward_pass(jinput_vals(i),W1,b1,W2,b2);
    derivW1 = -1 * W2'.* sigmoidDerivative(jA1) *jinput_vals(i);  

"jA1" is already return from the "sigmoid()" function and so repeated unnecessary sudden increase and decrease of lamba problem solved.
